# Setup for Taxonomy throwing 404 constantly

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm running a fresh, vanilla install of Drupal 7.27. There are absolutely no non-default modules installed with it. I was playing with the taxonomy settings to familiarize myself with the system. I have no trouble creating vocabularies, terms and hierarchies, or associating content, but editing any of my existing terms takes me out of the overlay mode, and saving the edits throws a 404 Object not Found. Further, setting urls for any of my taxonomy terms breaks the landing page for the term, giving me, for example:

```
Page not found
The requested page "/drupal-7.27/?q=/nonfiction/cookbooks" could not be found.
```

in the content area of the page.

Any ideas where I can look for the source of this error? The error log in admin reports simply tells me what I already know.

I'm new to Drupal, just hoping to get my company to migrate away from Magento, so this is all very exciting, but confusing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a rewrite-rules not working. Are you sure your .htaccess is used for this install?

Comment: I haven't configured any special privileges for Drupal on .htaccess. I'm running it off of localhost on my test rig. What would I need to give it?

Comment: mod_rewrite for apache needs to be enabled and you need to make sure AllowOverride All is enabled in your virtual host for your drupaldirectory. https://drupal.org/node/54832 more here.

Comment: Excellent. I will have to try that tomorrow.

Comment: @Marcel Wonderful! After a big-ol' fight with the vhost and apache's conf files, I got .htaccess working and the situation resolved itself. You should write that as an answer so I can +1 you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpected non-reachable pages you know that exist are 99% of the time a problem in the server-config.

mod_rewrite for apache needs to be enabled and you need to make sure AllowOverride All is enabled in your virtual host for your drupaldirectory. more here: http://drupal.org/node/54832

After you have this setup right you can also enable clean-urls and lose the ?q= in your url. Set it up @ admin/config/search/clean-urls.